# ¿Cómo rellenar latitud y longitud en tabla MySQL con direcciones?

Tags: php, mysql, geocodificación

Tengo una tabla mysql que tiene 3 campos, dirección, latitud y longitud. Los datos se cargan desde un fichero a través de php que solo tiene las direcciones, y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que la longitus y latitud se calculen o rellen automáticamente.
Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Sin haberme enfrentado nunca a ese problema, simplemente te doy algunas ideas de como lo podrías lograr:

Puedes buscar alguna API o servicio web que te devuelva dichos valores a partir de la dirección. Supongo que (por ejemplo) la API de Google Maps proveerá de dicho servicio.

Esto consiste simplemente en que hagas un cURL y hagas la petición a dicha dirección con el parámetro "dirección" que te pida la API.

Luego simplemente analiza como te devuelve los resultados esa consulta, extrae los que te interesen (latitud y longitud) e introducelos en tu base de datos.

Ignoro si la API te dará problemas a la hora de hacer una petición desde un dominio diferente (CORS). Eso es algo de lo que te tendrás que informar. Haciendo una busqueda rápida en Google he encontrado esta página, por ejemplo:

https://www.bufa.es/google-maps-latitud-longitud/

Es simplemente que investigues como hacer la petición a la dirección en cuestión.

Comment: Grcias @cooper he estado mirando lo que me comentas y la verdad es que está muy bien pero no me serviría ahora pues han cambiado las necesidades. ¡Gracias!